# What would be the best way to backup and restore mysql dumps with just php?

Tags: php, mysql

I know how you do it from the console, and I know you can execute console commands with php, but would there be a way to recursively dump a database into a file, and then restore it from that file later, just using php? I want it to be able to work on windows and nix servers.

I am guessing it would need to loop through the tables and rows but how would I get a list of those? Or can it even be done? Seems like it would take a massive amount of memory if db was a good size. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'sql/backup.sql' FROM my_table");
mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'sql/backup.sql' INTO TABLE my_table");
```

Comment: Note that the SELECT INTO OUTFILE will fail if the file exists. And the database process needs write permission in the target directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec()` function to call mysqldump.  This would pipe the output of mysqldump (the database export) back to your PHP script and you can handle it there however is necessary.  This can be used to export a single table or an entire database.  The tool could be installed on a client machine, or the PHP script can be run on the MySQL server.

```
/path/to/mysqldump --host=[svr] --user=[user] --password=[passwd] [db]
```

Make sure that the user passed to MySQL has `SELECT` and `LOCK TABLE` permissions on each database to be backed up.

Comment: You could just dump it straight into a file (mysqldump dbname > dump.sql), and then from there gzip it and serve it, rather than return it to PHP. Doing that could cause memory issues with large databases.

Answer (score 0):

Run the SHOW TABLES; query. Walk through the results and run the queries listed by deizel for each table.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) might help with primary keys

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table
```

Answer (score -2):

Look into the mysql database.

Comment: Why was this down voted? You can get PK information out of there.

Comment: I suspect it was downvoted because the answer is to vague to be useful.