# Copy MySQL structure across servers via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in need of help - I've got two mysql databases on different servers with a web host, and I need to copy a Joomla installation from one to the other. The problem I have is that the only way I can access the data is via php, as direct odbc connections to the database are locked down.

I don't mind doing it table by table, but have no idea of how to code the script :(

My knowledge of php is limited (hence using Joomla), so if anyone has a couple of minutes to point me in the right direction, it'd be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

PG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you install [phpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.net/)? If so, it has a database export/import functionality that would likely be perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks CeeJay, There's a scaled down version of phpMyAdmin on the 1and1 control panel that they've muddled around with - I've found the export link and managed the migration in seconds :) Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post.

[What would be the best way to backup and restore mysql dumps with just php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459796/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-backup-and-restore-mysql-dumps-with-just-php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html), though I would try phpMyAdmin first as the other poster has suggested.